# PyInstaller 3.3 EXE fails to locate SDL2.dll

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

PyInstaller generates an EXE of my code without fail. However, the EXE that is generated throws an exception

```
Exception: unable to locate: SDL2.DLL
```

Inside main.spec:

```
a = Analysis(['main.py'],
         pathex=['E:\\Roguelike'],
         binaries=[('SDL2.dll','.'),('libtcod.dll', '.')],
```

I have looked around online to find similar problems and solutions and have even appended

```
try:
    import win32api
    win32api.SetDllDirectory(sys._MEIPASS)
except Exception:
    pass
```

to the file. Libtcod, which is the library that requires SDL2, loads fine but cannot find SDL2.dll. The executable works in one directory mode.

Comment: look in `C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Temp` while your executable is running and find the tmp directory that your application has unzipped itself to and see if the file is there to start with ... . then try printing `os.listdir(sys._MEIPASS)` (inside your python executable) and make sure it shows up there

Comment: @JoranBeasley According to print(os.listdir(sys._MEIPASS)) SDL2.dll is inside of the path.

Comment: try doing `os.environ["PATH"] = sys._MEIPASS+";"+os.environ["PATH"]` and maybe `sys.path.insert(0,sys._MEIPASS)`  just cause you specified it for win32api does not mean libcotdl or whatever respects that setting it likely uses os.environ["PATH"]

Comment: @JoranBeasley Neither of those worked, either.